# How to add a subchild on a xml file using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm following following the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) about how could i modify an existing xml file in order to add a subchild value inside the record child.

**Original xml file:**

```
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="system_type">osx</value>
  <record name="service">
    <value name="threads">1</value>
  </record>
</Values>
```

**Current code:**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')


values = tree.getroot()
list_languages = values.getchildren()

processing = ET.Element('value')
processing.attrib['name'] = 'cpu_use_limit'
processing.text = '20'

values.append(processing)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

**Current output:**

```
<Values version="2.0">
      <value name="system_type">osx</value>
      <record  name="service">
        <value name="threads">1</value>
      </record>
      <value name="cpu_use_limit">20</value>
</Values>
```

**desired  xml file:**

```
<Values version="2.0">
      <value name="system_type">osx</value>
      <record  name="service">
        <value name="threads">1</value>
        <value name="cpu_use_limit">20</value>
      </record>  
</Values>
```

Comment: Nope, your last edit is wrong. There is no trace of "threads" in the input *xml* or the code, so there's no way that it's present in the output.

Comment: I just edited, to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to start with one remark: the input *XML* seems wrong (semantically), because you have a root node *Values*, which has children *value* **and** *record* (which doesn't seem to belong here).

But, considering that the *XML* is correct, then you don't want to add the newly created node directly under *Values* node, but under *record* (which is a child of *Values*). To find out that node, [[Python 3]: **findall**(*match, namespaces=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) is used.

*code.py*:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = ET.parse("data.xml")

    values = tree.getroot()
    list_languages = values.getchildren()

    processing = ET.Element("value")
    processing.attrib["name"] = "cpu_use_limit"
    processing.text = "20"

    relevant_nodes = values.findall("record")
    for relevant_node in relevant_nodes:
        relevant_node.append(processing)

    tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

After running the code,

*output.xml*:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="system_type">osx</value>
  <record name="service">
    <value name="threads">1</value>
  <value name="cpu_use_limit">20</value></record>
</Values>
```

Comment: QUick question, i forgot to mention that the original file contains <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> , but on the output this line isn't present. How could i generate a new file with that information?

Comment: Edited the answer (`tree.write` part).